# Git: Viewing log info for revisions ahead of the currently checked out one

Tags: git

Just wondering,

If I check out a git revision behind the most recent, then run git log, it only shows logs up to the currently checked out revision - not the most modern.

So, how do I view log info for branches ahead of my currently checked out revision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have checked out a different revision, then you are no longer on the original branch. So you can still run

```
git log branchname
```

to get the full log of the branch you are interested in.

If you only want to see the different log entries

```
git log ..branchname
```

Which will show all log entries between your current branch and the branch name specified.

You can do this for any two branches:

```
git log branch1..branch2
```

Comment: And depending on how prolific a brancher you are, the `--all` option might be useful.